# order place() and order save()

Tags: magento2, php, orders, multishipping

I found this code at `Multishipping.php`, but i dont know what the function, is `save()` function is saving the order?

Multishipping.php :

```
$order->place();
$order->save();
```

And how could i save an order to database 2 times?

Comment: What do you mean by saving the order twice, do you mean to duplicate it twice under the same tables or into a different table? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I tried to modified on multishipping and it's already so complicate to explain it, and  the last thing i need to do is duplicate the order under the same tables. I tried to change the order id each time i want to duplicate the order, but it's all just made error on the sql. Is there a way for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly,

- `$order->place();` => processing payment.
- `$order->save();` => saving order data.

Comment: can i save the same order 2 times?